# Value set via Intent.putExtra doesn't persist

Tags: android, android-intent

I am writing an application that runs a service in the background. This service receives intents with instructions to do something and then performs those actions in another thread. `Intent.putExtra()` is used to include information about the action that ought to be performed.

If by some chance the action fails, a notification is created indicating this to the user. The notification includes a "retry" button that can be used to retry the failed action.

This is done as follows, where `intent` is the Intent that was originally used to start the service:

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LAST_FAIL, 1234);

new Notification.Builder(context)
        ...
        .addAction(
                R.drawable.ic_action_retry,
                context.getString(R.string.action_retry),
                PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0)
        )
        ...
```

My expectation is that the intent will contain the new data (`EXTRA_LAST_FAIL`) when it is delivered to the service, but this is not the case:

```
int lastFail = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_LAST_FAIL, 0);
if (lastFail != 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "action failed last time");
}
```

However, despite setting the value to `1234` above, the re-delivered intent does not contain `EXTRA_LAST_FAIL`. `getIntExtra()` returns 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0)
```

Replace that with:

```
PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

If an earlier equivalent `PendingIntent` is still considered to be outstanding, `getService()` effectively returns that existing `PendingIntent`. `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` will replace the extras.